JIRA JQL Número de distintos asignados a tickets
En un filtro de JIRA, necesito contar el número de distintos asignados a tickets de un proyecto. Por ejemplo, si hay 13 personas que tengan algún ticket asignado, la cuenta daría esos 13. Lo he intentado mediante aggregateExpression pero no estoy dando con la fórmula.
Ejemplo de lo que he intentado:
project = "Contratos" AND issueFunction in aggregateExpression("Total Asignados", "Assignee.count()")

Este caso no devuelve nada. Con group by no sé cuál es la sintaxis.
Muchas gracias.

Hola buenas, que tal si pruebas a editar tu pregunta y agregas lo que has intentado nos sera muy util para poder ayudarte gracias!!

Ok, pongo un ejemplo en la pregunta. Muchas gracias.
